# Wordpress Canonical URL Facebook Like button

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a Facebook Like button using iFrame on a page similar to http://domain.com/blog/competition-entries/?pid=6

There are a number of pages i.e. ?pid=7, ?pid=8 etc but when I added the Facebook code it always likes http://domain.com/blog/competition-entries

I have SEO by Yoast plugin installed but can't work out how to have current URL as og:url tag.

Any pointers grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook probably ignores $_GET parameters (anything after ?) so I think the only solution is to use permalinks - which you should use in the first place. Any good reason you dont? As an added bonus that also adds a bit to your SEO ;)

To enable them just go `Settings->Permalinks` and select one - my suggestion would be `Day and name` if you post a lot or `Month and name` if you're not that frequent writer.

Comment: Permalinks are enabled but the page calls a gallery plugin [imagebrowser id=2] which then creates the dynamic page/s. Any other suggestions? Thanks too by the way

Comment: Well the URL is not working for me, so I couldn't tell.  Are you using a plugin for galleries?

Comment: The url is not live yet and yes, I am using NextGen Gallery

Comment: Gallery->Options "Activate permalinks"

Comment: Well I can't help any more since I don't see what's going on. If you are comfortable with writing custom functions that overwrite default ones than look into the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)